# Problems reading gyroscope

Tags: android, gyroscope

I´m developing an app that reads the gyroscope and generates a graph with its values. I already did it using the accelerometer **(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)** and it did fine, but when I use the **gyroscope(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)**, the app closes.

I´m using SDK 16, and looking into the class the **type_gyroscope** is marked as deprecated, but I tried the SDK 21 and continued having the same problem. Does someone know what is happening?

LogCat:

10-05 02:10:58.117 3934-3934/com.smartapps.accel E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null
10-05 02:11:00.700 3934-3934/com.smartapps.accel D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM                                                                                                                             --------- beginning of crash
10-05 02:11:00.703 3934-3934/com.smartapps.accel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.smartapps.accel, PID: 3934
                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
                                                                       at com.smartapps.accel.MainActivity.openChart(MainActivity.java:114)
                                                                       at com.smartapps.accel.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:103)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Post your logcat during app crash.

Comment: @bukkojot the sensor manager is getting null